# Setting the Date Format in the SQL*Loader Control File

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, to-date

I have csv file that has "17 September, 2009 11:06:06 AM" as COMPLETED_ON variable

I am using sql loader to load data to oracle with folowing:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'c:/load/file_name.csv'
APPEND
INTO TABLE tbl_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
(
COMPLETED_ON DATE "not sure what to put here",
)
```

in oracle I have this column created as follows:

"COMPLETED_ON" TIMESTAMP (0) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE

How do I change COMPLETED_ON date in control file?

Comment: If Ed Gibbs' answer solved your problem, please accept his answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not 100% with the `LOAD DATA INFILE` syntax, but I know the format string `'DD Month, YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'` matches your date format. I was able to use it in a `TO_DATE` to convert your sample date. Try this:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'c:/load/CW_COMPLIANCE.csv'
APPEND
INTO TABLE tbl_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
(
COMPLETED_ON DATE 'DD Month, YYYY HH:MI:SS AM',
)
```